# Finding source of second call to own page in devtools

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Debugging a page where I see that there are two calls made to the page, one is the initial call and one is made when the first has been recieved and the browser parses the document. I am however having trouble finding the source of the second call. I have built the javascript i dev mode so I have sourcemaps but the call seems to be originating from the html code itself. Looking in the Network tab of devtools I see this
[image: Chrome devtools]
in Chrome and this

[image] in Firefox

Firefox seems to identify the Initiator as image but no more details as to what image.

What should I look for in the code to find the source of the call? Is there something else I can do to get more details of where the call is made from?

Update:
Clicking the initator item in Chrome marks the first Doctype line in the document
[image]

Comment: And what happens if you click the "(index)" entry in the Initiator column in Chrome? That normally opens the source in the Sources panel and highlights the line where the request originated.

Comment: Clicking the (index) in the initiator marks the first Doctype line in the page. See update i post

Comment: Is that page publicly available or can you provide a reduced test case, so the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: yes, it is public: https://www.holmgrensbil.se/bilar-till-salu/

Comment: Found the culprit. It's a `background-image: url('');` style in the `<div class="page-header">`. I've updated my answer to also cover definitions in CSS and added a detailed description for how to find such issues.

Comment: I also want to note that [according to the CSS specification it's actually wrong that browsers send network requests for empty `url()` functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#url-empty). For Firefox [I've filed a bug some years ago](https://bugzil.la/1302991) to get that fixed, and [for Chrome there's also a bug filed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=910954).

Comment: Note that the Firefox bug just got fixed. So, starting from Firefox 87 there won't be any requests for `url('')` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the request is recognized as an image is an indication for either an `<img>` HTML element or a `url()` CSS function that has a URL that references the document itself instead of an image.

### Check the HTML

From my tests, this does not happen when the `src` attribute is empty but it happens when you set it to an anchor on the page.

So, in order to find the culprit, go to the *Inspector* (Firefox) or *Elements* (Chrome) panel, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (macOS) and search for `img[src^="#"]`. That finds all `<img>` elements that have a `src` attribute with a value starting with a hash.

### Check the CSS

Browsers (incorrectly) send a network request when the CSS `url()` function is set to an empty string, i.e. `url()`, `url('')`, or `url("")`.

To check whether it is set within the `style` attribute of one of the HTML elements, search for `url('')` and `url()` within the *Inspector* as described above.

If it cannot be found there, you need to search within the style sheets.

**Chrome**

In Chrome this is possible by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (macOS) while the focus is within the DevTools. Doing so opens a search tool that allows to search across all loaded sources. Type `url('')` in there and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If nothing is found, try it again with `url("")` and `url()`.

**Firefox**

In Firefox there's no such global search yet (as of Firefox 85), unfortunately. Though there are two ways other ways to search through the style sheets.

1. Via the Style Editor
   The [*Style Editor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Tools/Style_Editor) allows you to inspect the style sheets, though you have to search in each one separately by selecting it at the left side and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (macOS), typing `url()`, `url('')`, or `url("")` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Via the Network Monitor
   There's a feature that allows you to [search through the network request reponses within the Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list#search_in_requests). Click the magnifying glass button, which opens the search tool. In the input field type `url()`, `url('')`, or `url("")` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Scanned all image tags without finding anything that point to the current page or similar. Also checked anything with # without any luck